# Performance Monitor for ASP.Net applications

Tags: iis, performance, windows-server-2012, asp.net, performance-monitoring

I have an IIS hosted ASP.Net site which is experiencing timeouts. I would like to be able to monitor it from every angle but I'm not sure where to start with configuring PerfMon counters.

Does anyone know of a sort of template for PerfMon for monitoring ASP.Net applications on Windows 2012?

Answer (score 0):

If you utilize nagios you can write your own custom monitoring routines.